# Filter rows on the condition that at least two distinct key words must be present

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe with speech data, like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:12,
  partcl = c("yeah yeah yeah absolutely", "well you know it 's", "oh well yeah that's right", 
             "yeah I mean well oh", "well erm well Peter will be there", "well yeah well", 
             "yes yes yes totally", "yeah yeah yeah yeah", "well well I did n't do it", 
             "er well yeah that 's true", "oh hey where 's he gone?", "er"
))
```

and a vector with key words called `parts`:

```
parts <- c("yeah", "oh", "no", "well", "mm", "yes", "so", "right", "er", "like")
```

What I need to do is filter those rows with at least **two distinct** `parts` values. What I can do is filter those rows with at least two `parts` values, regardless of whether they're distinct or the same:

```
library(dplyr)   
df %>%
  filter(
    str_count(partcl, paste0("\\b(", paste0(parts, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")) > 1
  )
  id                            partcl
1  1         yeah yeah yeah absolutely
2  3         oh well yeah that's right
3  4               yeah I mean well oh
4  5 well erm well Peter will be there
5  6                    well yeah well
6  7               yes yes yes totally
7  8               yeah yeah yeah yeah
8  9         well well I did n't do it
9 10         er well yeah that 's true
```

How can I assert that the matched `parts`be distinct so that the result is this:

```
  id                            partcl
1  3         oh well yeah that's right
2  4               yeah I mean well oh
3  6                    well yeah well
4 10         er well yeah that 's true
```

Comment: If, say, the matching words were`'yeah'`, `'oh'`, `'no'` and `'well'`,  you could attempt to match the following regular expression: `^(?=.*\b(yeah|oh|no|well)\b.*\b(?!\1)(?:yeah|oh|no|well)\b)`. There will be a (zero-width) match if and only the string contains two (or more) distinct words from the given four-word list. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WFXii4/1). Hover the cursor over each part of the expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this helps - extract the key words with `str_extract_all`, and then do the check with `n_distinct` to `filter` rows having more than one unique keyword

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  filter(map_lgl(str_extract_all(partcl, 
    paste0("\\b(", paste0(parts, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")), 
    ~  n_distinct(.x) > 1))
```

-output

```
 id                    partcl
1  3 oh well yeah that's right
2  4       yeah I mean well oh
3  6            well yeah well
4 10 er well yeah that 's true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over `parts` with `sapply()` to check `df$partcl` for occurrences of the keywords. The `paste0("\\b", x, "\\b")` part ensures that we only detect full words, otherwise "so" will also be found in "absolutely" for example. `rowSums()` creates a vector we can add to `df` and we can then `dplyr::filter()` the desired rows.

```r
library(dplyr)

df$distinct_parts_count <- 
  sapply(parts, \(x) grepl(paste0("\\b", x, "\\b"), df$partcl)) |> 
  rowSums()

df |> 
  filter(distinct_parts_count >= 2)
#>   id                    partcl distinct_parts_count
#> 1  3 oh well yeah that's right                    4
#> 2  4       yeah I mean well oh                    3
#> 3  6            well yeah well                    2
#> 4 10 er well yeah that 's true                    3
```